# Storing Objects and retrieving them from Mule Registry

Tags: mule, mule-el

I have included a key/value pair in the following location:
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org/mule/config/registry-bootstrap.properties. The Mule documentation states that that is where they should be placed for loading them at start up.
The entry in the file is shown below:

```
 myObject=org.sys.jks.DataConstants

  class DataConstants{
      public static final String GGS="FST";
   }
```

The class has a list of static final variables.  However, when I try to access the constants in my flow I'm not getting any values. Here are my attempts below.

```
     #[app.registry.myObject.GGS]
     #[app.registry.'myObject'.GGS]
```

Unfortunately, neither works. How do I access the constants as keys of a map in the payload?

For example #[payload['app.registry.myObject.GGS'] doesn't work.
 Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Documentation, you can try #[app.registry.get('nameOfBean').nameOfConstant]

.get() documentation:

> Returns the value to which the specified key is 
>    mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the 
>    key. 
>   More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a 
>    key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : 
>    key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it 
>    returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.) 
>   If this map permits null values, then a return value of 
>    null does not necessarily indicate that the map 
>    contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that 
>    the map explicitly maps the key to null. The 
>    containsKey operation may be used to distinguish 
>    these two cases. 
>   Parameters:
>       key the key whose associated value is to be 
>        returned
>   Returns:
>       the value to which the specified key is mapped, or 
>        null if this map contains no mapping for the key
>   Throws:
>       ClassCastException if the key is of an 
>        inappropriate type for this map (optional)
>       NullPointerException if the specified key is null 
>        and this map does not permit null keys (optional)

In my case, I am adding the bean in memory in my global.xml mule configuration file with:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="beanUtils" name="beanUtils"
        class="somepackage.NameOfClass"
        scope="singleton" />
</spring:beans>
```